# Difference between aggregated data and connected data

Tags: database, nosql, neo4j

Neo4j is a nosql (graphical) database , which is optimized for connected data.
what is the difference between aggregated data and connected data ?

Answer (score 1):

Does the tutorial help explain the difference? http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorial-comparing-models.html

In my understanding...

Connected data is about there being relationships between different entities e.g. there could be a relationship 'WORKS_FOR' between a person and a company.

Aggregated data is about how you might use aggregation in your model to simulate relationships when you can't explicitly define them e.g. a company might contain a collection of the people who work there or a person might contain a collection of the companies they've worked for.

Mark

Comment: can you please cite some example ?

Comment: I did include an example in the reply with respect to modelling a company and the people who work for the company. What else are you looking for that would make it easier to understand the difference?